# Как добавить значение третей таблицы в результат JOIN двух таблиц

Tags: sql

Плдскажите пожалуйста, есть 3 таблицы:

1) Cities
        
`| id     | name     |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | Москва   |
| 2      | Сочи     |`

2) Auto

```
| id     | name     | adress        | city_id |
+--------+----------+---------------+---------+
| 1      | Тойота   | ул. Ленина    | 1       |
| 2      | Ниссан   | ул. Мира      | 2       |
```

3) Cash

```
| id     | number   | description   | auto_id |
+--------+----------+---------------+---------+
| 1      | 1        | касса 1       | 1       |
| 2      | 2        | касса 2       | 2       |
```

.

```
  SELECT auto.name AS 'Авто', concat(cities.name, ' ', auto.adress) AS 'Адрес авто с городом', cash.number AS 'Номер кассы', cash.description AS 'Описание кассы'
      FROM auto INNER JOIN cash  
         ON auto.id = cash.number JOIN cities ON cities.id = city_id ORDER BY auto.name
```

Данный запрос выше соединяет 2 таблицы, появилась необходимость соединить adress и cities.name, что бы в конечном результате получилось - Москва ул. Ленина, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Comment: Сделайте еще один join - ON cities.id = city_id

Comment: Сделал, получилось, но почему то добавился id в строку, я добавил concat может из за этого? Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Так укажите `id as city_id` после строчки адреса авто с городом

Comment: Так не работает, ошибка

Comment: Проблема в concat, если делать отдельными столбцами то норм

Comment: Я извиняюсь, все работает, просто адреса совпали и я запутался  )

Answer (score 0):

Запрос в вопросе соединяет 3 таблицы, вот третья, условие соединения правильное:

```
JOIN cities ON cities.id = city_id
```